# Contact form javascript verification outplayed

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, google-chrome, console

I am administrating an old site that has a contact form. It is is being verified by javascript to filter out junk mails. Lately the client is complaining of getting some junk every now and then.

The form has an `onsubmit` attribute that calls a javascript function which verifies if everything is filled out correctly. It also has captcha verification.

I found that it can be outplayed with google chrome console just by submitting the form with jquery or javascript like `$('form').submit();`.

Is there a way to prevent this or should i change the site to do a php verification after submit?

Comment: In an ideal scenario a server side validation should always be in place.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it the 'ideal' scenario, it's more like 'every possible scenario'. You're lucky your contact form has not yet been discovered by spammers (probably because of the lack of reach). Server side validation _is_ key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the attribute is `onsubmit="verifyfyunction"`

remove the attribute & replace it with a submit event handler

```
jQuery(function($,undefined) {
   $('form').on('submit',verifyfunction);

});
```

you should do a php check indeed for those users disallowing javascript